# VBA copy paste range into corresponding range for rows with content

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet called "SicknessRecordGraded" which has a varying number of rows.
Columns A - F (1 - 6), have raw content to calculate.
Then from columns I - AG (9 - 33) there are a range of formulas which calculate the information in A - F.
I am preparing a vba macro to auto copy the range of formulas from I - AG into each row where there is content in A - F.
I have been attempting to write the macro as follows. I have the range to copy correct using the .resize function, however I have not figured out how to paste into the correct range.

```
    Public Sub experiment2()


Dim rw As Long
rw = 3

    ' Select initial sheet to copy from
    Sheets("SicknessRecordGraded").Select


    ' Find the last row of data - xlUp will check from the bottom of the spreadsheet up.
    FinalRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ' For loop through each row
    For x = 1 To FinalRow

            Cells(rw, 9).Resize(1, 33).Copy ' Resize from intial range. Columns I - AG.

             NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Continue incrementing through the rows.
            Cells(NextRow, 1).Select ' Find the next row.
            ActiveSheet.Cells(NextRow, "I").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll ' Paste information.
            Sheets("SicknessRecordGraded").Select 'Reselect sheet to copy from. Probably uneccessary.

    Next x
End Sub
```

I would assume that the line to amend would be

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(NextRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll ' Paste information.
```

to include another range function.

Comment: Are you aware that `Cells(x, 9).Resize(9, 33)` resizes to a range of 9 rows x 33 columns, not a one row range from column 9 to column 33?

Comment: It doesn't appear so. That is useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the range you wish to start the paste in is `Cells(NextRow, 1)` then you would simply use:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(NextRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

or:

```
ActiveSheet.Paste Cells(NextRow, 1)
```

Comment: Ok, so how do I paste the range into columns I - AG?

Comment: If the `NextRow` value is correct, use: `Cells(NextRow, "I")` instead of `Cells(NextRow, 1)`

Comment: Ok, I have edited my code above to incorporate your suggestions. Now it is copying the correct range, into the correct range. However, it is now pasting into the row after the rows where A - F have content.

Comment: I suspect you want to use: `NextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row + 1` so it goes to the next blank row in col I, not col A.

Comment: Great. Problem resolved. Code works. Thanks a bunch.